# In App purchase in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app with facility of In App purchase 
but application crashes on the falloling code

var List = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

and it shows me up

the explicit transaction has been forcibly cancelled. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8032000F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CurrentAppSimulator Class is used in Windows Store app it's not working in Windows Phone-8 App.

Answer (score 2):

You should use CurrentAppSimulator while developing your app and CurrentApp when deployed to production.